# Division by a second query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to first query by the second one, how would I go about this?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Result
FROM pparsdb.application
    INNER JOIN pparsdb.planning_scheme
    ON application.planning_scheme = planning_scheme.ps_code
    WHERE planning_scheme.markus_ra = 'GA'

SELECT Result / COUNT(*)
FROM pparsdb.planning_scheme 
WHERE markus_ra = 'GA'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) / crss.totalCount AS Result
FROM    pparsdb.application
        INNER JOIN pparsdb.planning_scheme
            ON application.planning_scheme = planning_scheme.ps_code
        CROSS JOIN
        (
            SELECT  COUNT(*) totalCount
            FROM    pparsdb.planning_scheme 
            WHERE   markus_ra = 'GA'
        ) crss
WHERE   planning_scheme.markus_ra = 'GA'
```

Comment: if this does not work, please do tell me so I can update or delete it `:)`

Comment: I'm just reading about cross joins trying to understand them.

Comment: How would I have divided the other query for sake of knowing it?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have only one planning scheme per application, here is an approach that uses just one query with no subqueries:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.planning_scheme) / COUNT(*) AS Result
FROM pparsdb.planning_scheme ps left outer join
     pparsdb.application a
     ON a.planning_scheme = ps.ps_code
WHERE ps.markus_ra = 'GA'
```

Even if that condition doesn't hold, you can do:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.planning_scheme) / COUNT(distinct ps.planning_scheme) AS Result
FROM pparsdb.planning_scheme ps left outer join
     pparsdb.application a
     ON a.planning_scheme = ps.ps_code
WHERE ps.markus_ra = 'GA'
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative, just deciding which is better :-P